# Icomoon: Xcode build failed after removed icomoon.ttf, still runs normally

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting an Xcode build error after I deleted icomoon.ttf since I wasn't planning on using it any longer. How can I get rid of this annoying build error? App still launches and runs normally, though. I guess I need to alter my Info.plist file, but I don't want to mess anything up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- Open `ios/<projectName>/project.pbxproj` and Info.plist.

Find any remaining references to that font and remove them.

[image]

- In Xcode run Product, Clean Build Folder
- Restart JS sever, run build or `react-native run-ios`.

In Info.plist if you don't need any other special fonts you could remove the fonts key and the array.

[image]

I tested with a new RN Project, since I don't need any special fonts I don't have any UIFonts key in Info.plist.